# Python Object Array Sorting Loop

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have an insertion sorting function that sorts number in a 1D array, but as soon as I edit it to accept a 2D array with strings attached to the numbers there are many repeated rows in the output, which also is not sorted anymore.

Here is the sorting function, A is the 2D array, where A[i][0] is the number and A[i][1] is the string.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
def insertionSort(A):
    for i in range(1,len(A)):
        temp = A[i]
        while i > 0 and A[i-1][0] > temp[0]:
            A[i] = A[i-1]
            i = i-1
        A[i] = temp
    print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you wish to sort each row of the 2D list.

```
def insertion_sort(A):
    for sub in A:
        #Note*
        for i in range(1,len(sub)):
            temp = sub[i]
            while i>0 and sub[i-1]>temp:
                sub[i] = sub[i-1]
                i=i-1
            sub[i] = temp
    print(A)
```

*Note that sub refers to the object of inner lists. So any change made to sub will be reflected in the inner lists...